# Vanilla JS modal issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

This seems like a simple idea to me clearly I'm missing something here and any advice on what is wrong would be appreciated. I have created a simple modal that will pop up when the button is clicked. I assumed by using an If/else statement in the JS function i could just chose to set the button ti show or to disappear. I know of work arounds for this but I'm curious why this solution will not work

```
function openNav() {
    let open = document.querySelector('#open');
    open.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let nav = document.querySelector('nav');
        nav.style.display = 'block';
        if (nav.style.display === 'block') {
            open.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            open.style.display == 'block';
        }
    })
}
openNav();

function closeNav() {
    let close = document.querySelector('#close');
    close.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let nav = document.querySelector('nav');
        nav.style.display = 'none';
        if (nav.style.display === 'block') {
            close.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            close.style.display = 'none';
        }
    })
}
closeNav();
```

the button does work to open the modal after it is closed tho the "open" button does not re appear.

Comment: Uh, ok.  Take a step back for one moment and re-examine what each method is doing with the `nav.style.display` and any if logic you are doing.  You should see a code smell immediately.

Comment: I'm sorry what?

Comment: When clicking open, it sets the nav display to block.  And then tests, is the nav display block?  Of course it is.  Same sorta logic in the close as well.  The if logic is unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change it to toggle too since you should only use this function once for adding the event listener

```js
function toggleNav() {
    const open = document.querySelector('#open');
    const close = document.querySelector('#close');
    const nav = document.querySelector('nav');
    
    open.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.style.display = 'block';
        close.style.display = 'block';
        open.style.display = 'none';
    })
    
    close.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.style.display = 'none';
        close.style.display = 'none';
        open.style.display = 'block';
    })
}
toggleNav();
```

```css
#close, nav {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button id="open">Open nav</button>
<button id="close">Close nav</button>
<nav>Nav</nav>
```

a few more errors:

```
if (nav.style.display === 'block') {
   open.style.display = 'none';
} else {
   open.style.display == 'block'; // This is a comparison
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the open button back to block when the nav is closed. Try this code instead:

```
function openNav() {
    let open = document.querySelector('#open');
    open.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let nav = document.querySelector('nav');
        nav.style.display = 'block';
        open.style.display = 'none';
        close.style.display = 'block';
        /*
        if (nav.style.display === 'block') {
            open.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            open.style.display == 'block';
        }
        */
    })
}
openNav();

function closeNav() {
    let close = document.querySelector('#close');
    close.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let nav = document.querySelector('nav');
        nav.style.display = 'none';
        open.style.display = 'block';
        close.style.display = 'none';
        /*
        if (nav.style.display === 'block') {
            close.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            close.style.display = 'none';
        }
        */
    })
}
closeNav();
```

I think you are assuming that the if block is monitoring the `display`. However, it does not, it only checks it once in the function call.

Comment: Ahh, okay so this is more or less what I was assuming. so that would explain why it was happening. thank you.

Comment: If the code works out, feel free to mark it as an answer. If not, I'll see where I messed up. Thanks!